# Simple Java MVC (swing)

Tags: java, mvc, swing

I'm a Java beginner currently practising MVC pattern and came up with this. Could you please check if this is a proper implementation of MVC and if there are any best practices that I have broken?

```
public class Appka {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Model model = new Model();        
        Controller controller = new Controller(model);              
        View view = new View(model, controller);        
        model.addListener(view);

    }
}


public class Model {

    String value;
    List<StateChangedListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public Model() {

        this.value = "";
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        notifyListeners();
    }

    public void addListener(StateChangedListener l) {
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    public void removeListener(StateChangedListener l) {
        listeners.remove(l);
    }

    public void notifyListeners() {
        listeners.forEach(l -> l.stateChanged());
    }
}


public class View extends JFrame implements StateChangedListener {

    private Model model;
    private Controller controller;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JButton button1;     
    private JButton button2; 

    public View(Model model, Controller controller) {
        this.model = model;
        this.controller = controller;
        initComponents();
    }


    private void initComponents() {

        button1 = new JButton();
        button2 = new JButton();
        label1 = new JLabel();
        label2 = new JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        button1.setText("1");
        button1.addActionListener(controller);


        button2.setText("2");
        button2.addActionListener(controller);

        label1.setText("label1");

        label2.setText("label2");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(button1)
                    .addComponent(label1))
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(label2)
                    .addComponent(button2))
                .addContainerGap(113, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(label1)
                    .addComponent(label2))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(button1)
                    .addComponent(button2))
                .addContainerGap(30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }


    @Override
    public void stateChanged() {
        label1.setText(model.getValue());
        label2.setText(model.getValue());
    }

}

public class Controller implements ActionListener {

    private Model model;

    public Controller(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton clicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
        model.setValue(clicked.getText());        
    }

}

interface StateChangedListener {

    public void stateChanged();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

(this answer is advice and not a real code review, but I can't comment)

I discourage to use swing for your GUI. Java is replacing swing with JavaFX. 
But that's not the only reason why I should use JavaFX. The most important reason is that with JavaFX it is easier to follow the MVC pattern.

A very good JavaFx and MVC tutorial I really recommend and wich shows the whole worflow and structure:
[link](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/)

Comment: I think giving an advice about not using something and supporting this claim with good arguments is also a valid review.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems:

1. You connected the buttons instead of the text fields to your model.
2. You have two text fields but only a single value in your model. In proper MVC, each text field should be attached to a different property of the model.
3. You always send a change event. Your model should only send change events when the new value isn't the same as the old one.
4. You should tell your `StateChangedListener` which aspect of the model changed. Pass the name of the property, for example.